# NSMutableURLRequest: posting large amounts of data

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsmutableurlrequest

I need to send large amounts of data (image files) by POST in a `WebView`, so I'm using `NSMutableURLRequest` with `setHTTPBody:`.

Problem: if the data size is more than about 3MB, the app suddenly starts eating up huge amounts of memory and gets dog slow with all the paging.

I've tried changing this:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:post.Get() length:post.Size()]];
```

..to this:

```
[request setHTTPBodyStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:
    [NSData dataWithBytes:post.Get() length:post.Size()]]];
```

..but then nothing seems to happen and the request just times out. I get none of the normal callbacks (like `WebViewProgressEstimateChangedNotification`) and the data doesn't seem to get set.

So, how do I (a) make the `NSData` approach not be a memory hog or (b) make the stream approach work (assuming it's a good workaround)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by using `NSURLConnection` to do the upload manually, and then feeding the result into the `WebView`. As a bonus, I get much better upload progress updates this way.